# what's the best way to implement loopback on an existing node.js project

Tags: node.js, strongloop, loopbackjs

I have successfully created a few loopback projects using

```
slc lb project *myproject*
```

command but now I have a pre-existing node project that I would like to use loopback in.

Is there a recommended best practice around the migration to loopback?

Is it just a matter of including the relevant module references in my package.json and running `npm install`? Or do also need to make some changes to my app.js?

Will I need to manually create the models.json and datasources.json?

Any insignts appreciated.

Edit:  I added the relevant loopback modules to my package.json, replaced my express requires with loopback, manually added a datasources.json, and models.json and it all seems to have worked.

The only remaining issue is that when I bring up my explorer view the shell comes up but no api endpoints even though I have models defined in my models.json file.

Answer (score 1):

> Edit: I added the relevant loopback modules to my package.json, replaced my express requires with loopback, manulally added a datasources.json, and models.json and it all seems to have worked.
>
> The only remaining issue is that when I bring up my explorer view the shell comes up but no api end points even though I have models defined in my models.json file.

To load and process `models.json` and `datasources.json`, you have to "boot" your LoopBack application.

Assuming you have installed loopback 2.x in your project, and you want to use the old 1.x project layout scaffolded by `slc lb`, here are the instructions:

1. Install loopback-boot 1.x. Make sure you are not using 2.x or newer, as 2.x changed the project layout.

   ```
   npm install --save loopback-boot@1.x
   ```
2. Modify your main application file (e.g. `app.js`) and add the following lines:

   ```
   // at the top
   var boot = require('loopback-boot');

   // after you have created `app` object
   // and configured any request-preprocessing middleware
   boot(app, __dirname);
   ```

Please consider using the new 2.x project layout, see [Migrating apps to version 2.0](http://docs.strongloop.com/display/LB/Migrating+apps+to+version+2.0) for information on how to migrate your "models.json" into the new format.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a recommended best practice around the migration to loopback?

I suggest scaffolding a new app using `slc loopback` and moving your old apps files to the relevant directories.

> is it just a matter of including the relveant module references in my package.json and running npm install or do also need to make some changes to my app.js?

This will be part of the migration process, you will also need to configure `app.js` to meet your needs (like setting up middleware, etc)

> will I need to manually create the models.json and datasources.json?

No, when you scaffold the app using `slc loopback`, they will be automatically generated in the new project.

> The only remaining issue is that when I bring up my explorer view the shell comes up but no api end points even though I have models defined in my models.json file.

Did you create the files in `commmon/models` manually? Try creating them through `slc loopback:model` and the tool will add the configurations in `server/model-config.json` for you.